# c++ thread can not reuse deallocated memory that allocated by main

Tags: linux, multithreading, c++11, ubuntu-16.04

I have a problem when create new object by main thread and then delete it, after that I create it again using the same function by Thread and found that my memory(monitor from htop) grow up. Am I wrong on this code or this is its behavior?

```
void createAndDeleteObj()
{
    std::vector<SomeObj *> objVector;

    //   create object
    for( size_t i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i )
    {
        objVector.emplace_back( new SomeObj() );
    }

    //   delete object
    for( size_t i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i )
    {
        delete objVector[i];
    }
}

void main()
{

     createAndDeleteObj();

     //  memory not increase
     createAndDeleteObj();

     // memory increase equal to the first time used
     Thread thread1( createAndDeleteObj );

     thread1.join();

     // call this function by thread again, memory not increase 
     Thread thread2( createAndDeleteObj );

     thread2.join();

     //  memory not increase
     createAndDeleteObj();
}
```

Since the concept of Thread share the heap space, i dont know why it always allocate new memory for Thread, why it does not use memory allocated by main even if it is freed.

Comment: How do you build the program? What optimization flags are you using? And have you checked the generated code to see what it does, maybe there's some optimization that affects your running performance and memory usage?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i compile using g++ with only -g flag with c++11, no other flag. I have never check the generated code, could you advise me how to checked the generated code?

Comment: Creating a thread uses memory.

Comment: Use the [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org) and you can see the generated code online, and see how it changes depending on the flags you use or what happens if you change compiler (or even version of the same compiler).